# Asynchronous vs synchronous read in node comparison

Tags: node.js, libuv

I am doing a small performance comparison on reading files synchronously and asynchronously in node. So I wrote a small script,

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");

const read = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
(async() => {
    try{
        console.time("async read 65MB file");
        await read("./size_65mb.pptx");
        console.timeEnd("async read 65MB file");

        console.time("sync read 65MB file");
        fs.readFileSync("./size_65mb.pptx");
        console.timeEnd("sync read 65MB file");


        console.time("async read 3MB file");
        await read("./size_3mb.pptx");
        console.timeEnd("async read 3MB file");

        console.time("sync read 3MB file");
        fs.readFileSync("./size_3mb.pptx");
        console.timeEnd("sync read 3MB file");


        console.time("async read 135KB file");
        await read("./size_135kb.pdf");
        console.timeEnd("async read 135KB file");

        console.time("sync read 135KB file");
        fs.readFileSync("./size_135kb.pdf");
        console.timeEnd("sync read 135KB file")

    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})()
```

Surprisingly, the result was,

```
async read 65MB file: 148.487ms
sync read 65MB file: 25.268ms
async read 3MB file: 8.368ms
sync read 3MB file: 1.167ms
async read 135KB file: 0.499ms
sync read 135KB file: 0.081ms
```

Now, It looks like node is quite performant in reading files synchronously rather than in its asynchronous version. (at least in macOS, node v10).

Is there any reason why one should prefer reading files asynchronously in node ? Are there any pro(s) and con(s) in reading file either way ?

Comment: It depends what your program/server/script is doing. Imagine a server that reads a big file synchronously everything else in the event loop will wait for your synchronous task to finish and the handle of other requests will be slower.

Comment: @MickaelB. that one thing to consider.